# SenchaTouch - Move items from one panel to another

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

To handle orientation change, my first move was to modify the main panel's layout type from `hbox` to `vbox` and vice versa depending on the orientation, but Sencha doesn't allow dynamic layout change for the moment, then I found an idea on the internet.
Someone suggested to create 2 panels, one `hbox` and the other `vbox`, and when there is an orientation change **move** items from one panel to another, and show/hide the correct one, say I have this code below :

```
{
    xtype: 'panel'
    id: 'landscape-panel',
    layout: 'hbox'
    items: [
        // My items
    ],
}, {
    xtype: 'panel',
    id: 'portrait-panel',
    layout: 'vbox',
    hidden: true
}
```

How can I move `landscape-panel` items to `portrait-panel` ?

Comment: var hboxItems = Ext.Viewport.down('panel[id=landscape-panel]').getItems();  Ext.Viewport.down('panel[id=portait-panel]').setItems(hboxItems);

Comment: I think it would be better,to add items on both panel,and make the one panel visible at a time.

Comment: I have a map, that wouldn't be wise

Comment: @ProtoBassi It gives me this Error : `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works like a charm :

```
if (Ext.Viewport.getOrientation() == 'portrait') {
    var backupItems = Ext.getCmp('login-landscape-panel').items.items.slice(0); // clone array

    Ext.getCmp('login-portrait-panel').add(backupItems);
    Ext.getCmp('login-landscape-panel').removeAll();

    Ext.getCmp('login-landscape-panel').hide();
    Ext.getCmp('login-portrait-panel').show();
} else {
    var backupItems = Ext.getCmp('login-portrait-panel').items.items.slice(0); // clone array

    Ext.getCmp('login-landscape-panel').add(backupItems);
    Ext.getCmp('login-portrait-panel').removeAll();

    Ext.getCmp('login-portrait-panel').hide();
    Ext.getCmp('login-landscape-panel').show();
}
```

Comment: you don't need the loops :) add can take an array, and cache your components in a variable in stead of fetching them every time.. it's more cpu intensive (so slower) like this. But nicely done ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is what i would do in ExtJs it's almost if not completely the same in touch

http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/vx5739qn/

```
var viewport = Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    layout: 'border',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        itemId: 'landscape-panel',
        layout: 'hbox',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'component',
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            html: '<div>component 1</div>'
        }, {
            xtype: 'component',
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            html: '<div>component 2</div>'
        }]
    }, {
        xtype: 'panel',
        itemId: 'portrait-panel',
        layout: 'vbox',
        hidden: true
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});

var orientationChange = function (orientation) {
    var ppanel = viewport.down('#portrait-panel'),
        lpanel = viewport.down('#landscape-panel'),
        items,
        isHorizontal = (orientation === 'H');

    if (isHorizontal) {
        items = ppanel.items.items;
        if (items.length > 0) {
            lpanel.add(items);
            ppanel.removeAll(false);
        }
    } else {
        items = lpanel.items.items;
        if (items.length > 0) {
            ppanel.add(items);
            lpanel.removeAll(false);
        }
    }
    ppanel.setVisible(!isHorizontal);
    lpanel.setVisible(isHorizontal);
};

orientationChange('V');
//orientationChange('H');
```